# Geometry Nodes Edge Damage AND Damage Material

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I send to here a picture of Geometry Nodes applied to the default cube. The red arrows point at the places where it is recommended to modify the values in order to give variation to the edge damage.

Just a little bit of help to anyone interested in doing the same setup: The dark blue "Multiply" nodes are made like this: Shift+A(to add Nodes) > Vector > Vector Maths. Then set it to "Multiply". (It is in my opinion much easier to find and set up the other nodes.)

I don't want to pretend that I invented this geonode setup. I found it here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujKChriPz5Y
All respect to this Andrew Wells who set up the Youtube channel.

Now my problem: Does anyone here know how to set up mixed Materials so that one Material goes specifically to the damage areas?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe debaser is right, anyway if you want to test the 2 materials you can add them with 'Set Material' node before boolean inputs, one for each geometry...

[image: materials setup]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt do materials in nodes, i gets to unprecise. Make your materials, UV Unwrap the mesh, and do it in texture painting mode. It could be smart to make seam lines around the "damaged" areas, so that your UV has these specific areas seperated. It also could be smart to just bake the normals from your damaged cube onto a normal one, then you can get enormous results by just adding one material.